# How to create JWT token for zoom?

Tags: integration, jwt, security-token

I have tried Following code But It didnt work.

```
Public Static String createToken() {

        String alg = 'HS256';
        String typ = 'JWT'; 
        String iss = '{API Key}';
        String exp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
         System.debug('exp'+exp);
        String headerJson = JSON.serialize(new Header(alg,typ));
        String bodyJson =  JSON.serialize(new Body(iss,exp));

        String token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(headerJson))
                + '.' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(bodyJson));
        String signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.signWithCertificate(
                'HMACSHA256',
                Blob.valueOf(token),
                '{API Secret}'
                ));
        token += '.' + signature;

        return token;
    }
    private class Header {
        String alg;
        String typ;
        Header(String alg,String typ) {
            this.alg = alg;
            this.typ = typ;
        }
    }



    private class Body {
        String iss;
        String exp;
        Body(String iss, String exp) {
            this.iss = iss;
            this.exp = exp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! A simple "it isn't working" isn't too helpful because the people who would try to help generally won't know _exactly_ how your code is supposed to work. Sometimes, it can help if you give some example input, the output you expect, and the output you're getting. If you're getting an error message, including the entire message (and stack trace) word-for-word is helpful. When working with third parties, looking through the third party's own documentation is generally the place to start.

Comment: About the only things I can see given my knowledge and the information you've provided so far are: 1) `HMACSHA256` is not a valid value for the algorithm to use for `Crypto.signWithCertificate()` (our choices seem to be `RSA-SHA1` and `RSA-SHA256`). 2) You aren't encoding the parts of the JWT as Base64_url_ (which is Base64 with '+' and '/' replaced with '-' and '_', respectively).

Comment: https://github.com/salesforceidentity/jwt is your friend

Comment: Thank You Derek, There was issue because of  Crypto.signWithCertificate(). I replace it with Crypto.generateMac(). Working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Code of Zoom JWT Token for zoom API Integration

```
Public Static String createToken() {

        String alg = 'HS256';
        String typ = 'JWT'; 
        String iss = '{API Key}';
        String exp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
         System.debug('exp'+exp);
        String headerJson = JSON.serialize(new Header(alg,typ));
        String bodyJson =  JSON.serialize(new Body(iss,exp));

        String token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(headerJson))
                + '.' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(bodyJson));
        String signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateMac(
                'HMACSHA256',
                Blob.valueOf(token),
                Blob.valueOf('{secret Key}')
                ));
        token += '.' + signature;

        return token;
    }
  //inner class
    private class Header {
        String alg;
        String typ;
        Header(String alg,String typ) {
            this.alg = alg;
            this.typ = typ;
        }
    }
     //inner class
    private class Body {
        String iss;
        String exp;
        Body(String iss, String exp) {
            this.iss = iss;
            this.exp = exp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful to others with similar problems if you explained what changes you made.

Comment: For others: In this case, since it appears that Zoom requires the JWT be signed with HMAC-SHA256, we can't use `Crypto.signWithCertificate()`. Instead, using `Crypto.generateMac()` and the private key of a key pair (which could come from a cert) does the work that needs to be done.